# Can't get copy to find last row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I had previous question on how to find the last row of data for a formula in Column A based on data in Column C.  And ya'll helped me figured that portion out!

Now I'm taking it a step further, and looping through more worksheets.
The data in Column C is Copying/Pasting correctly to the next available row.
However, the formula is pasting over the first set of data in Column A, versus finding the last row.

Better yet.. is there a way to make this formula a 1 liner??  I can't seem to get that to work either.

```
`Dim Mkts As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Destination Worksheet
    Set Mkts = Workbooks("Nielsen SC Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Markets")

'Copy 4Wk Data
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\cday\OneDrive - udfinc.com\Nielsen Scorecard\4Wk Data.xlsx"

    Dim Wb4 As Workbook
         Set Wb4 = Workbooks("4Wk Data.xlsx")

For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then
            
 'Find last used row in the copy range based on data in Column A
    Dim CopyLastRow4 As Long
        CopyLastRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in Column C, Offset 1 Row
    Dim DestLastRowC As Long
        DestLastRowC = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

 'Find last used row in the destination range based on data in Column C
    Dim LastRowColumnC As Long
        LastRowColumnC = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If .Index = 2 Then
    'Copy and Paste Data into C3
        .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & DestLastRowC)
    
    'Add Dates to Column A
        Dim FR As Range    'first row
        Dim LR As Range    'last row
            Set FR = Mkts.Range("A3")
            Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & LastRowColumnC - 1)
                Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 9, 28)"

    'Add Markets to Column B
        Set FR = Mkts.Range("B3")
        Set LR = Mkts.Range("B" & LastRowColumnC - 1)
            Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report1'!$A$1, 48, 13)"
    End If
    
    If .Index = 3 Then
        'Copy and Paste Data into C3
        .Range("A4:V" & CopyLastRow4).Copy Mkts.Range("C" & DestLastRowC)
    
    **'Add Dates to Column A
        Set FR = Mkts.Range("A" & DestLastRowC)
        Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & LastRowColumnC)
            Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report2'!$A$1, 9, 28)"
    'Add Markets to Column B
        'Set FR = Mkts.Range("B" & DestLastRowC)
        'Set LR = Mkts.Range("B" & LastRowColumnC)
            'Range(FR, LR).Formula = "=Mid('[4Wk Data.xlsx]Report2'!$A$1, 48, 15)"**
    End If

        End If
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: ` Find last used row in the destination range based on data in Column C` this comment looks like the comment for the previous block but the following code is operating on a different sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams  I updated the `LastRowColumnC` to be `Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`.  Is that what you mean?     Now it's filling in the first available row, but not dragging down to the last row of Column C.

Comment: Is "Nielsen SC Template.xlsm" where this code is running?

Comment: `LastRowColumnC` is found from `ws` but your're using it to create ranges on `Mkts` eg - `Set LR = Mkts.Range("A" & LastRowColumnC - 1)`

Comment: The Destination for the data paste is 'Nielsen SC Template.xlsm'.  But the data for the formula is being pulled from 'Wb4.ws' (Report: 1 - 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Mkts As Worksheet, ValA1
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Wb4 As Workbook, rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range
    
    'Destination Worksheet
    Set Mkts = Workbooks("Nielsen SC Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Markets") 'ThisWorkbook ?

    'Copy 4Wk Data
    Set Wb4 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cday\OneDrive - udfinc.com\Nielsen Scorecard\4Wk Data.xlsx")

    For Each ws In Wb4.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Index = 2 Or .Index = 3 Then
            
                'range of data to be copied from ws:  A4 to V[last row in colA]
                Set rngCopy = .Range("A4:V" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
                'destination for pasting in ColC
                Set rngDest = Mkts.Cells(Mkts.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                
                rngCopy.Copy rngDest 'copy the data
                'grab the value from A1 on Report1
                ValA1 = .Range("A1").Value            '<<<<<<
                'fill a range starting from rngDest two columns to the
                '  left and the same size (# of rows) as the copied range
                '  using part of the value from A1  
                rngDest.Offset(0, -2).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = Mid(ValA1, 9, 28)  'ColA
                'similar process for a column one to the left from rngDest  
                rngDest.Offset(0, -1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = Mid(ValA1, 48, 13) 'ColB
                
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Whoa buddy! That's more complex than my novice understanding. :)  Would you help me understand these lines: `Rpt1A1 = Wb4.Sheets("Report1").Range("A1").Value
                rngDest.Offset(0, -2).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = Mid(Rpt1A1, 9, 28)  'ColA
                rngDest.Offset(0, -1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = Mid(Rpt1A1, 48, 13) 'ColB`

Comment: See my comments above

Comment: Thank you for the break down!  I tried this code, and there's a hiccup.  A1 is different data on each report.  Example: Period : Latest 4 Wks - W/E 06/13/20 • Market : Chicago xAOC • Product Share Basis, Period : Latest 4 Wks - W/E 06/13/20 • Market : Cincinnati xAOC

Comment: I need A1 to move through the worksheets along with the copy Data.   For example: Report 1 (`.Index 2`), Copy A4:V, and paste in C3.  The take the line in Report1 - A1, and paste in Column A & B.

Comment: Then move to Report 2 (`Index 3`), copy that data from A4:V, and paste into the last available row in Column C.  The take the line in Report 2 - A1 and paste in the last available row in Column A & B.  Etc... while moving through the rest of the worksheet

Comment: Also, why `.value` and not `.formula`?

Comment: See edits above.   I used Value instead of formula since it seems those entries don't need to be "live" (as the other data from the same sheets is just copied as values)